# Change Local History Default Path In Sublime Text 3 Package Local Histroy

Tags: sublimetext3

How do I change the default path in the Sublime Text 3 Local History package settings file please?

```
LocalHistory.sublime-settings file:

{
  "file_size_limit": 262144, // 256 KB
  "history_retention": 30, // in days
  "history_on_close": false, // store history only on close
  "history_path": "<path>" // path to store history, defaults to <HOME>/.sublime/history
```

}

I would like to change the path to

```
"D:\SUBLIME TEXT 3\Sublime Text Build 3065 x64\History"
```

for example. Is this possible somehow?

I like to do this since I use the portable install and like to keep the History in the install directory as well.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
"history_path": "D:\\SUBLIME TEXT 3\\Sublime Text Build 3065 x64\\History" // path to store history, defaults to <HOME>/.sublime/history
```

did the trick and now Local History Package for Sublime Text 3 saves file copies in:

```
D:\SOFTWARE\SUBLIME TEXT 3\Sublime Text Build 3065 x64\History\
```